# disk partition not mount if window 8 or higher install with ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

we use `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdxn /dir/atwhich/u/mount`
but in windows 8 and higher error comes that:

```
The disk contains an unclean file system(0,0).
Metadata kept in Window cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdxn': Operation not permitted.
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully(no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how Windows implements "Hybrid boot", in which it essentially saves all of the kernel memory onto the disk (sort of a half-hibernate...it saves the kernel space memory, but not the user space memory) when you press "Shut Down" through the start menu.

You need to boot back into Windows and shut it down "fully" by running the command 'shutdown /s /t 0', in an Administrator command prompt. That forces Windows to *not* write the kernel memory data to the disk (the "Windows cache" that Linux is referring to). Additionally, you can make a shortcut to this command on your desktop to make doing full shutdowns easier.

After shutting Windows down fully, boot back into Linux, and all should be well.

See [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/) for a more detailed explanation of all of this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows machine, open control panel - then power options - then click on 'choose what power button does' on the left side - click on 'change settings that are currently unavailable', - under shutdown settings, un check 'turn on fast startup', then reboot into Ubuntu and you should be able to mount